# Merge request: [concatenate] and [concatenation]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Can we please merge [concatenate](/questions/tagged/concatenate) and [concatenation](/questions/tagged/concatenation)?

**Questions tagged [concatenate](/questions/tagged/concatenate):** 65
**Questions tagged [concatenation](/questions/tagged/concatenation):** 201

The two mean the same thing. One is a verb, the other a noun.

Comment: You should [suggest](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/concatenation/synonyms) it as a synonym

Comment: Maybe we could merge them as `[concatenateconcatenation]`

Comment: @Michael: I made [one](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/concatenation/synonyms). Please consider voting for it.